# How do I access Dependency Injection graph in .NET Core 2.0 ConfigureServices()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to migrate from .NET Core 1.1 to 2.0, and am stuck migrating the JWT Token configuration. I have an interface/class that provides the JWTBearerOptions, and in .NET Core 2.0 I cannot access my DI Graph objects (since in 2.0, JWT is configured in the **ConfigureServices()** function). I want to keep my Startup.cs file clean of so many lines of code configuring JWT.

Is there any way to delegate the JWTBearerOptions object creation to a provider created through DI? I want something like the below:

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(MyAuthicationScheme.JwtAuthName, options =>
            {
                myInjectedInstance.SetJwtBearOptions(options, Configuration);
            })
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean just creating an extension method? e.x. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/24/servicecollection-extension-pattern/

Comment: Is it possible for the custom service's constructor to be injected?

Answer (score 3):

@flodin 
I came across this same problem for the AddJwtBearer and there is a cludgey way to get access to the HttpContext by plugging into OnMessageRecieved Events

```
   jwt.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // setting the issuer validator delegate here instead of in the jwt.TokenValidationParameters
                        // allows for accessing the HttpContext items and DI container
                        context.Options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, parameters) =>
                        {
                            // di in callbacks!
                            var test = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITenant>();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on microsoft's docs. It is impossible to access DI objects during the ConfigureServices call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration#additional-notes

Comment: I think is only partly true. Since DI graph is being initialized in ConfigureServices it's logical that it can't be accessed there. However, many of the configuration calls there take callbacks that may be lambda functions. Those callbacks in turn will typically be called after the DI graph has been completed. In many cases you can take a IServiceProvider as argument to those callbacks. In some cases, e.g. AddJwtBearer(), you can't. That's a serious problem for me.